# How to overwrite the default style of a third party react component?

Tags: css, reactjs

The project I'm working on uses [react-responsive-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel) component but, although there is an attribute to change the arrows icon, there's none to increase the width of the button itself.

Is there a way for me to overwrite the padding on the component with custom css?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.carousel.carousel-slider .control-arrow {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Maybe also explain how css selectors work? The longer the css selector is, the more priority the css styling will be.

Comment: But where do I add this css? I tried creating as a style inside the jsx file but it didn't recognize the classes!

Comment: You might be able to `import "./MyComponent.css"` in `MyComponent.jsx`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to to use custom class on container that holds carousel component, and use it to override styles safely.

In your root css file:

```
.my-custom-class .carousel.carousel-slider .control-arrow {
  *styles*
}
```